# C++ private variable names and inheritance ambiguities

Tags: c++, variables, inheritance, private

This is about C++ (not java) inheritance and ambiguities in variable names.

Suppose that I am in this situation:

```
class A{
public:
void fct(){do something with x;}

private:
int x;
};

class B: public A{
private:
int x;
};
```

If I define some instance of the derived class

```
B foo;
```

and then call

```
foo.fct();
```

will `fct()` act on `A::x` or `B::x`?
I would like it to be acting on `A::x`. I wonder whether declaring x as private in class A is enough to make it safe against non-wanted ambiguities which may arise when defining derived classes.

I understand that just using a different name for `B::x` would be the best thing to do... but suppose that one is "distracted" and forgets that the private `A::x` exists, how bad the consequences would be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Since `fct` is non-virtual, it will always deal with `x` as a member of it's own class. It won't know anything about any other `x`s in any other classess.

However, if `fct` were to declared `virtual` and overridden in the child class, child override it would be called instead - and this one could be programmed so that it would use other `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `fct` will act on `A::x`. The fact that derived classes have member variables with the same name is irrelevant since the member is private and hidden from them.

If it were able to see `B::x` then that would be a bit like having virtual data!